# Camera tracking scene misalignment during animation render

Tags: camera, tracking

I am using camera tracking in Blender 2.8 to composite some bouncing balls onto a video background. I need the balls to disappear behind an object in the video (a plant), so I have created a second video from the orginal background video, with the plant cropped out and the rest of the field of view rendered as transparent. For the effect to work, the cropped plant in the second video needs to line up with the plant in the background video to allow the balls to pass 'behind' it.

I put the scene together in the compositor, and all seemed to be working well (see image below - I've rendered the overlaid the plant video in orange).

[image: Ball composited onto video background and plant overlaid (rendered in orange)]

The plants in the two videos line up perfectly when I render individual frames (F12), but when I render as an animation (with Ctrl F12), the alignment between the background video and the overlay is lost. In the complete animation sequence, the overlaid plant bounces around over the top of the background plant, whereas when I render each frame individually, the alignment is perfect.

[image: Misaligned images when rendered as an animation, compared with perfect alignment in individual frame rendering]

Why would this be happening? I suspect its something to do with the camera tracking (perhaps some interpolation across frames, based on camera momentum?), but I can't figure out how to fix it. Or are there better ways of doing what I'm trying to do...?

EDIT: Added a screenshot of the compositor nodes
[image]

Comment: please post an image of the compositing nodes.

Comment: did you enable motion blur?

Comment: Nodes added! And yes, motion blur is on (for the balls). That could be the issue, I guess. Will investigate!

Comment: The effect is still there with motion blur switched off, so that's not the cause...

Comment: I still haven't figured out the cause of this, but my workaround is to use a script to loop through and render each frame individually. Looks fine, but I still don't know why this is different to rendering an animation.